# How do I override the header in querySelectorAll with querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using datepicker-dialog.css and I have a querySelectorAll that retrieves a header in (.datepicker). However the .datepicker has a header that uses display:flex; which breaks the calendar displaying days vertically instead of horizontally.

Inside datepicker-dialog.css

```
.datepicker-dialog .header {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

In my index.html

```
<script>
    // Initialize the Datepicker-Dialog objects
    document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker').forEach(function (dp) { new DatePickerDialog(dp); });
</script>
```

I don't want to change the class directly because it is being used elsewhere so I tried adding a new class inside datepicker-dialog.css and calling querySelector.

```
<script>
    // Initialize the Datepicker-Dialog objects
    document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker').forEach(function (dp) { new DatePickerDialog(dp); });
    document.querySelector('.datepicker-dialog-mismatch');
</script>
```

Hoping that it would override the selectorAll but nothing changed. I then added

```
<style>
    .datepicker-dialog-mismatch .header {
        cursor: default;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 7px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: black;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
</style>
```

At the top of my html file but the issue still persist. What other options/functions I can use to override the header?

Comment: Can you share `datepicker-dialog.css` file and your `html`, `css` and `js` files? Because just selecting the class with `document.querySelector('.datepicker-dialog-mismatch');` won't do anything. Therefore need to clarify what is going on with your code.

Comment: https://replit.com/@JThao88/index#index.html

Comment: Where are your other `js` and `css` files that generate the `datepicker`? Only providing the necessary files related to your question can help the community to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were able to see the files on the left side of the site. https://replit.com/@JThao88/index#datepicker-dialog.css 
https://replit.com/@JThao88/index#datepicker-dialog.js

Answer (score 0):

The tablesorter function was overlapping my calendar and therefore caused it to display incorrectly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#view_table").tablesorter();
    });
```

Once I commented it out, the calendar worked as it should displaying the days horizontally.